# Vertical alignment of label followed by md-switch in angular material

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-material

I have a page in which a want to display some text in a `label` followed by a `md-switch`. I'm aware of the fact that I can remove the label completely and display the text after the switch, but this solution is not acceptable.

```
<md-content layout="row">
 <label class="md-title">text</label>
 <md-switch class="md-primary" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'" ng-model="vm.data"> {{vm.data}}</md-switch>
</md-content>
```

I cannot seem to align these elements vertically. The switch is always lower than the text, not under the label, after it but much lower.
Some suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't visualize that. Can you post a picture or a plubkr please ? This way I'd be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add layout-align="start center" attribute or replace "start" with "center" or "end" if you want other alignment:

```
<md-content layout="row" layout-align="start center">
 <label class="md-title">text</label>
 <md-switch class="md-primary" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'" ng-model="vm.data"> {{vm.data}}</md-switch>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but an optimal solution for me is one not involving css alterations.

Comment: @PetruScurtu please check answer now, i found better solution, without CSS

Comment: The layout-align tag is used for horizontal alignment, not vertical alignment.

Comment: No, you can specify both alignments, the first value in this tag is for horizontal alignment, and the second one is for vertical. You can check and experiment with this tag here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment